# Какая синхронизация лучше для асинхронного метода?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пытаюсь сделать свой класс на основе асинхронного метода System.Net.HttpClient.GetAsync

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;

    public class MyConnet
    {
        private string secret;
        private string baseUrl = "https://users.mysite.my";
        public string path { get; private set; }
        private HttpClient client;

        public MyConnet(string setSecret, string setPath)
        {
            secret = setSecret;
            path = setPath;
            client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async void GetUser(string UserInfoPath)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(baseUrl + UserInfoPath);
            try
            {                
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                /*
                                //Допустим я тут сделал проверку, пакет пришёл нормальный. Тогда
                                this.MessageForEvent = "Пакет пришёл";
                                this.MyEvent(MessageForEvent);*/
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Как лучше сделать синхронизацию? Прикрутить события к данному классу? Он маловат для этого.
Хотелось бы, чтобы он вызывал событие, которое описано в вызывающем потоке:

```
public delegate void MyEventSendMessageDelagate(string SomeMessageinEvent);
public event MyEventSendMessageDelagate MyEvent;
public string MessageForEvent = "NULL";
MyConnet UserManage=new MyConnet("HashOfPass","/Users/");
....
UserManage.GetUser("/id/secondName"); //+Передать информацию о событии или вызывающем потоке... Что?

 MyEvent += (s2) =>
            {
              //Обработчик пакета в основном коде.
             }
```

**UPD добавил код**
Суть синхронизации сводится к данным по событиям WebSocket.OnMessage и данные, которые получаю асинх методом HttpClient.GetAsync(url).

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void MyEventSendMessageDelagate(string SomeMessageinEvent);
        public event MyEventSendMessageDelagate MyEvent;
        public string MessageForEvent = "NULL";
        public bool FlagMain = false;//флаг признака начала второй части программы, когда к сайтам подключился
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyEvent += (s2) =>//пользовательское событие
            {
                if (!FlagMain)
                {
                    if (MessageForEvent == "Обработка пакетов начальная")//После начинаем "Текущую работу". То есть основную. Cas'ом
                                                                         //  Запускаем таск с постоянной обработкой пакетов. Ошибки как обраб - ивентами...
                    {
                        Site1_DataPrice.Apply_Decerialized(depthPackets[iPaketov - 1]);//depthPackets-буфер пакетов WebSocket
                        FlagMain = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (MessageForEvent)
                    {
                        case "Phase1":
                        case "Увеличить частоту запросов":
                            break;
//Здесь предполагается много case'ов, данных и состояний много будет
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebSocket webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://Site1.my");
            MyConnet Site2 = new MyConnet("Api","Secret","/Users/prices/");

            webSocket.OnMessage += (sender1, e1) =>
            {
             Action action1 = () => MyEvent(sMessageForEvent);
               if ((iPaketov > 5) && (bStartinit))
                    {
                        //Обработка пакетов..
                        b5PacketsRecieved = true;
                    }
              if (b5PacketsRecieved)
                    {
                      MessageForEvent = "Инициализация прошла";
                      Invoke(action1);//Вызываем польз СОБЫТИЕ
                    }
            };
        }
    }
/*******/
    public class MyConnet
    {
        private string apiKey;
        private string secret;
        private string baseUrl = "https://Site2.my";
        public string path { get; private set; }
        //"/v2/trading/placeOrder"
        private WebRequest request;
        private HttpClient client;

        public MyConnet(string setapiKey, string setSecret, string setPath)
        {
            apiKey = setapiKey;
            secret = setSecret;
            path = setPath;
            request = WebRequest.Create(baseUrl + path);
        }

        public async void GetOB(string instrument, string limit)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(baseUrl);
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                "После проверки вызов события MyEvent("пришёл пакет")"
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!" + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

TAP шаблон вроде не очень подходит?

Comment: Какой смысл тут в событиях? Почему просто не сделать `GetUser()` возвращаемым типом и уже с ним работать?

Comment: А при чем тут синхронно/асинхронно? Что вы дальше то хотите сделать с данными, который этот метод получает? Вы поясните нам, какова ваша задумка, зачем вам тут события?  Ведь вы можете сделать просто, `public async string GetUser(string UserInfoPath)` (лучше перевести в `Task<>`), тогда у вас будет вовсе `string user = UserManage.GetUser("/id/secondName");`, как видите сразу получите нужный результат, без всяких событий (`return` только в методе добавить не забудьте). Так вопрос у меня тот же: "Какой смысл тут в событиях?"

Comment: Мне казалось, что есть написать public async void GetUser(...) то метод будет исполняться асинхронно. Вроде асинхронно работает...  Чем еще синхронизировать, в этом и есть вопрос!!! Таких запросов будет 2 параллельно

Comment: У меня каждую секунду будут идти запросы к одному сайту. + WebSocket на другом сайте. В зависимости от данных с WebSocket я увеличиваю частоту запросов и их структуру... Post\Get  + часть данных сводится в единое целое. Данные из WebSocket получаю OnMessage событие. В будeщем хочу расширить и добавить еще 1-2 сайта на классе MyConnect (еще 2 объекта). Вопрос синхронизации всей этой информации. Как лучше.

Comment: А как вы запустите метод (например тот, который будет эти данные проверять) без этих самых данных (да и какой смысл в его запуске)?  Дожидайтесь их выполнения. Для того, что бы дожидаться выполнения задачи - придумали `Task`. То есть сделаем например [такой пример](https://pastebin.com/FVdCA1sS), как видите есть асинхронная задача `GetUser()`, которая вернет нам некое `string` значение, есть обычный метод, который вернет `bool` значение, ну и есть метод, который запустит это все. Программа асинхронно дождется выполнения `GetUser()`, потом запустит `CheckUser()`, выполнит `if` и даст результат.

Comment: Я в черновом варианте создал своё событие. Оно вызывается внутри события получения пакета WebSocket.OnMessage{ MyEvent("пришёл пакет")+частичная обработка } А внутри обработчика своего события MyEvent.OnEvent { по switch-case собирался указывать различные состояния программы }. Такая задумка. То есть обработчик данных главный внутри собственного события. (WebSocket вообще в отдельном потоке выполняется, библиотека Nuget, не особо вникал в детали где именно какой поток, но другой)
И в новом классе тоже хотел вызывать событие своё, таким образом синхронизация будет достигнута.

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо делать возвращаемое значение из асинхронной функции. Тогда вы сможете не только узнать, когда функция оьработала, но и получить от нее какой то результат на выходе. При таком подходе вам события просто будут не нужны. В этом и смысл TAP — избавиться от событий (EAP). [Подробнее тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/)